# Salesforce link with SSO

Tags: single-sign-on

We have put together an ADFS SSO system and have configured our SF org for it. We have a login site which users can go to, choose a system to login to, and are automatically logged in.

It works fine for Salesforce - but is there a way to have our Salesforce users automatically logged in whenever they got to https://www.salesforce.com ?

We do have a sub-domain which is the typical https://companyname.my.salesforce.com. Are we only able to have them logged in automatically if they use that sub-domain link ? Can we even do that - or are we limited to forcing our users to go to our SSO web site and choose Salesforce from there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to have our Salesforce users automatically logged in
>   whenever they got to https://www.salesforce.com ?

no

> are we limited to forcing our users to go to our SSO web site and
>   choose Salesforce from there ?

(assuming you mean Salesforce login that you configured) Yes

Comment: I think it’s worth mentioning that if SSO is properly configured, deep links should work without authentication, assuming AD already authenticated the user.